# SSIS - avoid files to open while executing them

Tags: ssis

I have this SSIS package which contains 5 execute package tasks. When I am debugging the main package I reach the execute package tasks and SSIS opens each package it is executing.

I don't need to see those 5 packages because I know they will work. Is there a way to only see my main package running in Visual Studio, while the other packages are running are being executed in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't indicate how you are creating your "main" package. I'll assume visual studio.

There is a way you can "almost" accomplish your requirement - you need to use breakpoints. Again, I haven't seen your package layout - but setting a breakpoint immediately **after** your 5 individual tasks should do the trick.

If they run on separate branches then you will need to alter your logic, but the principle remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am informed, this is NOT possible. Visual Studio will always open the packages in order to execute them - however, this is how Visual studio is capable of execution packages anyways. The only workaround which I know - but which has some risks which should not be underestimated: don't execute the packages via "execute package task" but via "script component". This should prevent the packages from being displayed. Anyways: as mentioned before, this has some risks and you should pay close attention to error handling, waiting (don't return from the script unless package has finished) and so on.